# How to get mmap'ed memory to sync to the file?

Tags: c, memory-management, posix, interpreter, mmap

I'm building a memory manager for my postscript interpreter and I want it to be able to suspend sessions to disk and resume a saved session. I designed it using an anonymous `mmap` and everything appears to work. The test code appears to have no trouble accessing the memory. But now that I've removed `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and provided a `O_RDWR` file descriptor, I can't see the memory contents in the file after the test has run.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit free malloc realloc */
#include <stdio.h> /* fprintf printf perror */
#include <string.h> /* memset */
#include <unistd.h> /* getpagesize */

#include <sys/stat.h> /* open */
#include <fcntl.h> /* open */

/* placeholder error function */
/* ultimately, this will do a longjmp back to the central loop */
void error(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    perror("last system error:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned pgsz /*= getpagesize()*/; /*=4096 (usually on 32bit)*/

/*
typedef struct {
    unsigned char *base;
    unsigned used;
    unsigned max;
} mfile;
*/

/* dump mfile details to stdout */
void dumpmfile(mfile *mem){
    printf("{mfile: base = %p, "
            "used = 0x%x (%u), "
            "max = 0x%x (%u)}\n",
            mem->base,
            mem->used, mem->used,
            mem->max, mem->max);
    unsigned u;
    for (u=0; u < mem->used; u++) {
        if (u%16 == 0) {
            printf("\n%06u %04x: ", u, u);
        }
        printf("%02x ", (unsigned) mem->base[u]);
    }
    puts("");
}

/* memfile exists in path */
int getmemfile(){
    int fd;
    fd = open(
            "x.mem",
            O_RDWR);
    return fd;
}


/* initialize the memory file */
void initmem(mfile *mem){
    int fd;
    struct stat buf;
    size_t sz = pgsz;

    fd = getmemfile();
    if (fd != -1){
        fstat(fd, &buf);
        sz = buf.st_size;
        if (sz < pgsz) sz = pgsz;
    }

#ifdef MMAP
    mem->base = mmap(NULL,
            sz,
            PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_PRIVATE
# ifndef MREMAP
            |MAP_AUTOGROW
# endif
            | (fd == -1? MAP_ANONYMOUS : 0) , fd, 0);
    if (mem->base == MAP_FAILED)
#else
    mem->base = malloc(pgsz);
    if (mem->base == NULL)
#endif
        error("unable to initialize memory file");
    mem->used = 0;
    mem->max = pgsz;
}

/* destroy the memory file */
void exitmem(mfile *mem){
#ifdef MMAP
    munmap(mem->base, mem->max);
#else
    free(mem->base);
#endif
    mem->base = NULL;
    mem->used = 0;
    mem->max = 0;
}

// ... omitting some address table functions not relevant here.


mfile mem;

/* initialize everything */
void init(void){
    pgsz = getpagesize();
    initmem(&mem);
    (void)initmtab(&mem); /* create mtab at address zero */
}

void xit(void){
    exitmem(&mem);
}

int main(){
    init();
    unsigned ent;
    int seven = 7;
    int ret;

    //printf("getmemfile: %d\n", getmemfile());

    ent = mtalloc(&mem, 0, sizeof seven);
    put(&mem, ent, 0, sizeof seven, &seven);
    get(&mem, ent, 0, sizeof seven, &ret);
    printf("put %d, got %d\n", seven, ret);

    unsigned ent2;
    ent2 = mtalloc(&mem, 0, 8*sizeof seven);
    put(&mem, ent2, 6, sizeof seven, &seven);
    get(&mem, ent2, 6, sizeof seven, &ret);
    printf("put %d in slot 7, got %d\n", seven, ret);
    //get(&mem, ent2, 9, sizeof seven, &ret);
    //printf("attempted to retrieve element 10 from an 8-element array, got %d\n", ret);

    unsigned ent3;
    char str[] = "beads in buddha's necklace";
    char sret[sizeof str];
    ent3 = mtalloc(&mem, 0, strlen(str)+1);
    put(&mem, ent3, 0, sizeof str, str);
    get(&mem, ent3, 0, sizeof str, sret);
    printf("stored and retrieved %s\n", sret);

    xit();
    return 0;
}
```

Running the test, checking the file.

```
josh@Z1 ~/xpost
$ make test
cc -g -Wall -Wextra -DTESTMODULE -o m m.c
./ob && ./m
put 7, got 7
put 7 in slot 7, got 7
stored and retrieved beads in buddha's necklace

josh@Z1 ~/xpost
$ od x.mem
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0200000

josh@Z1 ~/xpost
$
```

Do I need to *flush* it somehow? or close the file? <del>Oh. crap I bet that's it isn't it? Well I've spent some effort typing this, so I'll share. If it's too localized, so be it.</del> Nope. `close` doesn't change the output at all.

Update: It all appears to be working now. Final few problems were hardcoding the filename, omitting O_CREAT in the open() call. And other minor blunders. I've added `msync` for good measure, but `MAP_SHARED` is the *fix* for the above. This and related modules are viewable at http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you map things with `MAP_PRIVATE` the changes you make to the memory area are private to your process. To make the changes visible to anyone else (which writing to the file is), you need to map with `MAP_SHARED`.

Also, you need to set the size of the file with `ftruncate`. Otherwise the mmaped area just covers parts of the file that don't exist.

If you really want to make sure that the data ends up on disk, use `msync`, but normally you'll be able to see the contents you wrote into the mmap:ed area immediately unless you're on one of the few operating systems that doesn't have a unified buffer and object cache.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I had trouble earlier with MAP_SHARED going awry when a later mremap(...MAP_MAYMOVE) decided to move. But I'm rebuilding on Cygwin which doesn't have mremap.

Comment: Yep. `MAP_SHARED` did it. Thanks.